# Intuit Partner Platform - what return statuses should we be looking for to check if an OAuth token is still valid?

Tags: oauth, intuit-partner-platform

When going through the Intuit technical review, Intuit has indicated that we need to check within our app to make sure the OAuth token is still valid.

So far I've found at least two different return codes that can happen when an OAuth token is invalid - are there more than just two? What other return codes should we be looking for?

Found so far:

- HTTP 401 Unauthorized
- HTTP 200 OK + a ErrorCode 3200

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only HTTP status that should be used is 401 Unauthorized. Any other response status is either a bug or a faulty implementation of the specification on Intuit's side.

It may be that the token is valid, just not for the resource that you are trying to access. In these cases it is good to be pragmatic and really specify for the API consumer WHY they get a 401. It is perhaps this scenario that Intuit covers with a 200 + error code. But this is just a guess.

Comment: The endpoint that returns the 200 OK is Intuit's general "get available companies" endpoint, which basically should be available for any token, at any time. We'll see what they have to say about it. Thanks!

Comment: UPDATE: Intuit has responded to a support ticket I put in with them, and indicated that this is a BUG on their part - they *should* always be returning a 401 Unauthorized, but they are not. They have filed a bug report and will be fixing this.

Answer (score 1):

Keith,
keep in mind you should not have to check to see if a token is invalid, you should always know. If the customer disconnects then they are sent to an OpenId endpoint with the realm where you can find them on your side and disconnect them.

Alternatively if you disconnect, then you know its invalid.

But yes this is a bug it should only be unauthorized. I just wanted to pointout that you should know the state before calling under normal use cases.

Jarred

Comment: Hi Jarred - what if we're not using OpenID? This is for a Connect to QuickBooks Only app - we have absolutely NO OpenID components implemented, nor has Intuit indicated that we need to.

Comment: It's not required if you are only doing connect to QuickBooks, it is if you are listed on Appcenter. In either case when a user goes to Appcenter and disconnects we pass them back to you with an OpenId Assertion that contains the realm. ie. its there if you need it.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful! So to confirm - it's possible to use OpenID to detect this, even if we're NOT listed on AppCenter.

Comment: yes that is correct. OpenId is required when listed because we want SSO to happen to improve the customer first use experience when signing up for an application from AppCenter. But it has other uses for non-Appcenter apps.